# Setting JMenuItems border with Nimbus LaF

Tags: java, swing, border, nimbus, jmenuitem

i am modifying the appearance of some JMenuItems in a popup menu based on some parameters and the currently selected menu item.

This is a bit of pseudo code (pseudo, because it doesn't show all the complex process flow, but only the relevant parts of *setting the menu items properties*):

```
JMenuItem item= new JMenuItem("text");
Border border= calculateBorderForItem();
item.setBorder(border);
[...]
item.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    Color bg= calculateBackgroundForItem();
    item.setBackground(bg);
  }
}
```

This works quite well with the default Metal LaF, as well as with JGoodies PlasticXP LaF, but not with Nimbus LaF. Nimbus just ignores all these properties.

The background gets painted, when I set `item.setOpaque(true)`, but still the border doesn't show up. How can I force Nimbus to use my custom borders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `Nimbus LaF` by default to ignore `setBackground`, `setForeground`, etc.
- `Nimbus LaF` by default never to ignore `setBackground`, `setForeground`, in `Xxx(Cell)Renderer` (not somehow in the connection with your question)

---

there are two ways (by override)

- `JMenuItem`s `paintComponent()`, `paintBorder()`, `paintChildren`
- all proper [Keys in Nimbus Defaults](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html#primary),

Comment: Thanks. I have gone the way overwriting `paintComponent()` and `paintBorder()`. I am not fully happy that way, but it was the easiest to do without breaking the other LaFs.